# Grep subdirectories and save multiple outputs

Tags: ubuntu, unix, grep

I have 32 directories with one .pdb file each. How can I use grep on these files and save each to specific outputs?

The expected output is something like:

```
1.pdb > 1_clean.pdb
2.pdb > 2_clean.pdb
3.pdb > 3_clean.pdb
...
32.pdb > 32_clean.pdb
```

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
grep -r "^ATOM" *.pdb . > *_clean.pdb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**find** + **shell** solution:

```
find -type f -name "[0-9].pdb" -exec sh -c 'fn=$1; n=${fn##*/}; n=${n%.*}; \
      grep "^ATOM" "$fn" > "${n}_clean.pdb"' _ {} \;
```